# How to create .desktop files and new menu without alacarte?

Tags: desktop-environments

I want to do something like this:

My folder script contains ten scripts, I want to create *.desktop* files and new menu under Applications called "myScript".

I'm able to create *.desktop* with script but I don't want to use Alacarte but instead use a script process to make all in batch mode.

I cannot understand why the *.desktop* is shown only in category:Other. Yes I know it is possible to open Alacarte and move the launchers in any category, but for a batch process I want to do this with a script.

I don't know how to obtain information because I don't know how Alacarte works. I have tested some of my *.desktop* by inserting the `Category:Gnome;GTK;mymenu` but the launchers go in menu:"Other".

I hope my description is clear. I am using Gnome shell 3 with Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: There's only a few categories. You can't just make up random ones like "mymenu". :) Check out the main category list here:  http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html#category-registry

Answer (score 2):

ok finally i have find one solution, and one website is very useful to understand this: http://www.frankrock74.it/frankrock74/?p=1738
i do something like this:
open alacarte and made my personal menu "Script" as an empty menu.I can put this in any menu but i choose Application.
Now i create my personal .desktop file as is for example.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec= /home/$USER/myscript/script.sh
Name=script1
Icon=/home/$USER/image/icon.png
Categories=Script
```

Now is important to made one modification inside a file:
Terminal: gedit ~/.config/menus/applications.menu
in this file is possible to view the desktop directories created with alacarte,
example:

```
<Name>alacarte-made-1</Name>

<Directory>alacarte-made-1.directory</Directory>
```

this second voice is the menù i have created "Script"
to make the launchers functionally inside this desktop.directory
is necessary to add this line after the upper voice.
A directive to the menu to include our category
As is:

```
    <Include>
  <And>
    <Category>Script</Category>
  </And>
</Include>
```

in finally we have somthing like this:

```
        <Name>alacarte-made-1</Name>
    <Directory>alacarte-made-1.directory</Directory>
<Include>
  <And>
    <Category>Music</Category>
  </And>
</Include>
```

NOw saved and finally any my.desktop files i put inside the folder:
~/.local/share/applications/
is recognized in my personal menù and works well.
Is a good choice to read this web site to understanding desktop directories:
http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en
hoping my english is comprensible.
regards